# Machine learning applications in Architecture field

Tags: dataset, data, machine-learning-model

Can there be Machine learning applications in [Architecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Architecture) field?

Example : [New York City 100 years back](https://www.google.com/search?q=New%20york%20city%20100%20years%20ago&hl=en&prmd=inv&sxsrf=ALeKk00zyhq8VuzUZCx9RfaQeAN5sailBw:1597561242771&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjKjYezk5_rAhVlzTgGHbhgCgcQ_AUoAXoECA8QAQ&biw=360&bih=592) i.e. Year 1920, every ten years after 1920 and today i.e. Year 2020 images of New York City structures are feed as Input dataset of the Machine learning algorithm to predict the future Modern architecture  of Buildings, Offices, Parks, Museums, Shopping Malls etc look and feel in New York city say 1930, 1940, 1950 etc

Comment: *Can there be Machine learning applications in Architecture field?*  For a start, look into *generative design*.

Comment: Thanks Mark for your inputs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_design I mean Future modern architectural designs models in Buildings, Bridges, Malls, Museums, Parks, Libraries etc using Machine learning algorithms. It is possible using Machine learning algorithms. Isn' it?